# Distinct values in SPDataSource/DropDownList

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

How to get distinct values in asp:DropDownList control which is bound to sharePoint:SPDataSource control. But the remember the only tool i can use is sharepoint designer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible using only SharePoint Designer.

The answers of a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560550/what-is-the-best-way-to-retrieve-distinct-unique-values-using-spquery) all use code.