# Get unique values of parameter in Caml query

Tags: reporting-services, caml

I am generating SSRS reports using SharePoint list and using below Caml query in my dataset.

```
<RSSharePointList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                                          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ListName>Test_FAMM</ListName>
    <ViewFields>
       <FieldRef Name="Region" />
    </ViewFields>
</RSSharePointList>
```

However, I want to get only distinct values of the parameter.
Any modification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, CAML doesn't allow use of DISTINCT. There are a couple of workarounds that you may be able to use.

See:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77988/caml-query-on-sharepoint-list-without-duplicates

Or:
[What is the best way to retrieve distinct / unique values using SPQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560550/what-is-the-best-way-to-retrieve-distinct-unique-values-using-spquery)